# Negative Spacing in Kotlin Compose forEach

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I've tried to set a negative spacing on some circles, but I've had no luck with either:

`.padding(horizontal = (-5).dp)`

and

`.offset(x = (-5).dp)`

I'm not quite sure how to make this possible, I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

As you can see the image does include an overlay, but the images are behind each other.

Is there any way to achieve this in Kotlin Compose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it by wrapping second Image with a Box. Setting a background and offset.

```
@Composable
private fun ImageSample() {

    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .padding(20.dp), verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(100.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape1),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .offset((-20).dp)
                .background(Color.White, CircleShape)
                .padding(10.dp)
        ) {
            Image(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(100.dp)
                    .clip(CircleShape),
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.landscape2),
                contentDescription = null,
                contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
            )
        }
    }
}
```

[image]